# Passing arguments for a remote Python script using ssh

Tags: python, shell, ssh

```
Echo Enter the Report ID

read varname

ssh -t root@192.168.10.10 '
  python myscript.py --user User1 --password Password1 --report \$varname
'
```

I am trying pass an argument 'varname' to a remotely located python script using ssh but unable to do so. Getting an error 'Invalid report uuid provided'

Value for --report looks like as follow
    efc4c534-5d1d-11e9-844b-fa163e069095

Comment: What is the question here? What went wrong when you tried what you did above?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Question is updated. Hope will help!

Comment: sounds like this has something to do with your program/database and not SSH. Can you log into the machine and run the same command?

Comment: @PaulH For a static value of --report, program runs both remotely and locally. I would like to provide the value dynamically (during run time).

Comment: Why the \ before `$varname`? `varname` is define only locally, not on the remote machine.

Comment: @Keldorn I tried without \ and $ but couldn't get it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`varname` is defined locally only, so `$varname` needs to be expanded:

- Use double quotes instead of single quotes, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/6352677.
- Remove the backslash before `$varname`.

```sh
Echo Enter the Report ID

read varname

ssh -t root@192.168.10.10 "python myscript.py --user User1 --password Password1 --report $varname"
```

Comment: Depending on the value of `varname`, its expansion may need to be quoted on the remote end. `ssh ... "python ... '$varname'"` would suffice as long as you can guarantee that `$varname` itself doesn't contain any single quotes. If it could, things get a lot trickier.

Comment: Good point. In the case of OP's example (efc4c534-5d1d-11e9-844b-fa163e069095), that will probably not be necessary.

Comment: The sketchy thing is, though, that you are logging in to a machine as root using a script that effectively lets you run arbitrary code: consider `varname="; echo gotcha"`. It would be a good idea to validate `varname` against the expected input format and only run `ssh` if the validation succeeds.

Comment: True. Feel free to edit or delete my answer. This question looks like a duplicate anyway, and has a negative vote.